# Multi Collapsible /Accordion type table view in ios7

Tags: uitableview, ios7, accordion, collapsable

I need to create a table view like below image

[image: sample table view]

I want to load days first section click the first section inside location section and click the location i show the sublocation details in custom table view cell.how can i done this in ios

Answer (score 0):

I would first update the content of the cell after the user taps it (You should user a custom UITableViewCell), then calculate the new height of the cell for the tableview datasource and finally call the following two methods to give the accordion animation:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```